# CommentCase's CommentBody always blank when set via Apex

Tags: visualforce, controller, case

I have a small problem that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

I have a simple VisualForce page and controller to list and insert case comments. It displays comments fine but when I try to insert comments their CommentBody is always left blank. I use a middleware variable because the user in question does not have FLS access to the field. However I've tested it as a full system administrator and had the same issue (blank comments).

VF Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="ViewCaseController">
    Lipsum<br/><br/>

    <apex:repeat value="{!comments}" var="comment">
        {!comment.CommentBody}<br/><br/>
    </apex:repeat>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!cmtext}" label="Comment" />
        <apex:commandButton title="Add comment" value="Add comment" action="{!addComment}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class ViewCaseController {

    public Case c {get;set;}
    public List<CaseComment> comments {get;set;}
    public CaseComment cm {get;set;}
    public String cmtext {get;set;}

    public ViewCaseController() {
        c = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

        comments = [SELECT Id,CommentBody FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId=:c.Id];

        cm = new CaseComment(ParentId=c.Id);
        cm.IsPublished = true;
    }

    public PageReference addComment() {

        cm.CommentBody = cmtext;
        insert cm;

        return new PageReference('/ViewCase?id='+c.Id);
    }
}
```

The page is accessed with the ID parameter set to the ID of a case.

Comment: First thing I notice is your <apex:inputField> won't work being bound to an instance variable? This should be <apex:inputText> as it's not "on" a field of an object?

Comment: Also, if you are returning a page reference for the Visualforce page it should be to '/apex/ViewCase?id='+c.id) and I would recommend as you are creating a new record you want to see on the page reload you set it up with a pageRedirect to revisit the server. I have just copied this code into a DE and it doesn't work at all! ;) I will post you my contents in an answer and encourage you to try them, as it works perfectly for me.. :)

Comment: I don't need the /apex/* prefix as its going to be accessed via a Salesforce Sites site which is why I excluded it.

You're right about the inputField/text thing. That solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few bugs in your code (as per my comments on your question) which means you will not be getting the behaviour you are expecting. Try this VF page and controller and it should work for you..

```
public class ViewCaseController {

public Case c {get;set;}
public List<CaseComment> comments {get;set;}
public CaseComment cm {get;set;}
public String cmtext {get;set;}

public ViewCaseController() {
    c = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    comments = [SELECT Id,CommentBody FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId=:c.Id];

    cm = new CaseComment(ParentId=c.Id);
    cm.IsPublished = true;
}

public PageReference addComment() {

    cm.CommentBody = cmtext;
    insert cm;

    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/ViewCase?id='+c.Id);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
}
```

and

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="ViewCaseController">
    Lipsum<br/><br/>

    <apex:repeat value="{!comments}" var="comment">
        {!comment.CommentBody}<br/><br/>
    </apex:repeat>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText value="{!cmtext}" label="Comment" />
        <apex:commandButton title="Add comment" value="Add comment" action="{!addComment}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I have fixed the redirect in your controller and the input widget on your VF page.

The resulting page for me works (and reloads smoothly) for me:

[image: comments page]

Comment: The inputField to inputText change solved my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help :)